# How to run web pages without starting eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I have created a dynamic web application using eclipse.  it consist of java servlet and jsp  and it run on tomcat 7.2.it runs fine under any browser if run it through a eclipse, copy the address and paste it in browser while eclipse is running. I wish to run this application without running eclipse. for this i run the tomcat manually using startup command. however than when i use the website address of my web site in the browser it says resource not found. I want to run this without actually running eclipse. any suggestion please.

Comment: Have deployed your module to your installed tomcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to deploy the war file that was built by Eclipse to your new Tomcat server. You can just copy it to `<tompcat-instrallation-path>`/webapps location. It will be exploded by Tomcat automatically and you'll be able to see your pages at:

```
 http://localhost:<port>/<name-of-your-war>/...
```

Where `<port>` is usually 8080 if you didn't change it in Tomcat's config and `<name-of-your-war>` is the name of your war without `.war` extension.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to take the built war file, name it ROOT.war, and place it in the /webapps directory in your tomcat directory.  Tomcat gives instructions for this, you will replace the ROOT.war that is there by default.  You should also check to make sure you are using the same port on which Tomcat is running.